# How to extend TimePicker widget?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I want to disable past time numbers in TimePicker. In DatePicker there is a special property for disabling past dates and there is no one for TimePicker so I need to extend an original TimePicker. As I understand I need to change a layout. How to get access to the layout?

[image: Desired layouts to change]

**Important**: `android/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/time_picker.xml` is not an answer - it has got a reference to TimePicker widget where there are no links to other layout files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending a timepicker, extend from dialogfragment and on your onCreateDialog() method return a timepocker dialog. Also remember to implement OnTimeChangedListener so that you can validade the selected date as you need. If you're creating a picker  thats gonna be used throughout your whole application you should also consider overriding onDismiss() and then pass the selected date to the activity which started it. Hope this helps

Comment: I do not want to validate any selected time - I want to make past hours and minutes grey (unselectable) in widget layout.